# Django - Get all Columns from Both tables

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class DepartmentModel(models.Model):
    DeptID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    DeptName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.DeptName

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Department Table'

class EmployeeModel(models.Model):
    Level_Types = (
        ('A', 'a'),
        ('B', 'b'),
        ('C', 'c'),
    )

    EmpID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    EmpName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    EmpLevel = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="A", choices=Level_Types)
    EmpPosition = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentModel, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'EmployeeTable'  # Easy readable tablename - verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.EmpName
```

This is my models.py file

I have 2 tables and want to join both of them. also want all columns from both tables.

```
emp_obj = EmployeeModel.objects.select_related('EmpPosition'). \
                                                only('EmpID', 'EmpName', 'Email','EmpLevel', 'DeptName')
```

I have tried to do this but there is an error saying `EmployeeModel has no field named 'DeptName'`

How can I get all these columns?

Comment: `emp_obj = EmployeeModel.objects.select_related('EmpPosition').all()`
this will give you everything with its child table fields. But You must serialize this obj according to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all columns from both tables you don't need the `only` clause at all.  This is enough:

```
emp_obj = EmployeeModel.objects.select_related('EmpPosition')
```

If you do need to refer to the `DeptName` field of the employee you can follow the foreign key relationship by using a double underscore: `EmpPosition__DeptName`